# how to delete all variables attached to scope and rootscope and not the functions

Tags: angularjs

I have tried this:

```
for (var prop in $rootScope) {
  console.log($rootScope[prop])
    if (prop.substring(0,1) !== '$') {
        delete $rootScope[prop];
    }
    console.log($rootScope[prop])
}

for (var prop in $scope) {
  console.log($scope[prop])
    if (prop.substring(0,1) !== '$') {
        delete $scope[prop];
    }
  console.log($scope[prop])
}
```

But I end up deleting all the variables and functions attached to scope. I want to be able to delete all the variables/data and not the functions since I have to deal with a lot of data which is slowing down my application.

Also, please do tell if there are any other ways to deal with a problem like this.

Comment: Why not create one or more state objects and attach them to your `$rootScope` and then just delete or set them to `{}` without having to loop through all the scope properties?  Also, I would consider using services/factories to maintain state and allow them to clean themselves up accordingly.

Comment: Hey @dustmouse , That sounds pretty interesting. But pretty much new to this. Could you please direct me with an example? No Intentions to copy paste but would like to know more about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `typeof` operator to check if the property not is a function. You should also check for angular `$$` prefixed variables, such as `$$destroyed`, `$$isolateBindings` etc. This returns (as far as I have tested) *only* user defined variables (=what you have assigned to the `$scope` and nothing more) :

```
for (var prop in $scope) {
   if (typeof $scope[prop] !== 'function' && 
       prop.indexOf('$') == -1 && 
       prop.indexOf('$$') == -1) {

      //delete here 

   }
}
```

Comment: I would also add a 'hasOwnProperty' check, just to restrict the property search criteria.